# h2 class is not applying when loading dynamically

Tags: angular

I want to dynamically add h2 with a class for a div.

```
 <div class="row gx-4" [innerHTML]="holidaydeals">
    
    </div>
```

Now I will try to add h2 heading dynamically for above div

```
 ngAfterViewInit()
  {
 setTimeout(() => {
     
      this.holidaydeals="<h2 class='mb-4'>Ultimate Holiday Deals</h2>";
    }, 1000);

}
```

Anyway 'mb-4' class is not applying for the h2 header. Is there a way to apply class for the h2 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to bind the visibility of h2 with some boolean variable.
Something like this

```
 <div class="row gx-4" >
<h2 *ngIf="displayH2" class='mb-4'>Ultimate Holiday Deals</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you `ngIf` directive to achieve this. you could do that as follows.
in your HTML template

```
 <div class="row gx-4" >
  <h2 *ngIf="isHoliday" class='mb-4'>Ultimate Holiday Deals</h2>
 </div>
```

in your class file, define a global variable to store the display status of the `h2` tag

```
isHoliday = false;
```

then you can change the value of `isHoliday` variable to true from within a lifecycle hook.

for an example:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.isHoliday = true;
}
```